# iOS status bar: how to show some text there

Tags: iphone, ios

In top-most bar of iPhone screen, I don't know it's called status bar or not. I want to write some text on that after I finish some actions, is there any API for that or example?

Comment: I hope this is not possible. It completely goes against the UI of an iPhone. Why don't you use a toast? There's a tiny library (just two files) that nicely implements them: [iToast](https://github.com/ecstasy2/toast-notifications-ios).

Comment: Are you aware that you could set the status bar to hidden and create your own graphic area to display what you want?  Just thought I'd throw that out there, in case it did what you needed :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should find the gitHub project [MTStatusBarOverlay](https://github.com/myell0w/MTStatusBarOverlay) very useful. Drop-in class that allows easy yet powerful creation of custom status bar overlays. Some other classes that achieve the same thing can also be [found here.](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=status+bar)

Those saying this goes against good iOS design, I think that if used sparingly and only where appropriate, it can help de-clutter apps that have a lot of information already displayed on-screen.

EDIT: A good and current example of this is largely hyped email app [Mailbox](http://www.mailboxapp.com/). It uses status bar overlays to indicate progress of running tasks, freeing up the whole screen to display content!

Comment: Agreed, like how Twitter uses it when sending a tweet http://littlebigdetails.com/post/33363254165/twitter-ios-app-gives-feedback-in-the-status-bar

Comment: iOS Reeder also uses this to display a similar message: http://littlebigdetails.com/post/1487028562/ios-reeder-sync-indicator-via-simply-creative

Comment: Gmail also use that kind of status bar notifications.

Comment: andycam, know of any swift solutions?

Comment: @Mihado I haven't tested either of these but they advertise the same functionality in Swift 2.0 https://github.com/cezarywojcik/CWStatusBarNotification/tree/swift
https://github.com/jaydee3/JDStatusBarNotification/tree/feature/swift

Answer (score 3):

The status bar is meant for the operation system's use only - this means that it can show the time, network activity indicator, battery status and such but it is not customizable. I imagine that this is not exactly the case if you're talking about development for a jailbroken environment though.

An interesting option for you might be [creating a custom status bar](http://www.cocoaintheshell.com/2010/11/custom-status-bar-ios/).

**UPDATE**

Since I wrote this answer, I've come across several projects on Cocoa Controls that might help:

[KGStatusBar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kgstatusbar)

[FDStatusBarNotifierView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/fdstatusbarnotifierview)

[TWStatus](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/twstatus)

Seems as though this has become "sexy" since the MailBox app :)

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution is to display a secondary status bar underneath:

[iOS: Create a secondary status bar for displaying in-app messages](https://coderwall.com/p/jkdqra)

[image: hidden]
[image: visible]